# A brief response to salespeople's leading questions?

Tags: phrase-request, responses

How to respond shortly to suggestive questions such as:

> Do you want to buy this one or this one?

Those are very popular among tradesman and are of manipulative nature. I don't want to explain each time that I don't think such questions are proper, and that none of this option is to be chosen by me, and I don't wish to be asked such questions.

I need a short phrase for such questions, as short as possible, and not too offensive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As short as possible and as accurate as possible, you could say

> Neither, thank you.

or "No, thank you" or "None, thank you."

You could ignore the question, shake your head, or even just say

> I don't want any.

Answer (score 3):

In Buddhism there is the concept of [mu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_%28negative%29), which means 'nothing' in a sense of 'neither of the answers are suitable'.

I would just answer with *none*, *neither* etc... none of which are offensive or rude.

Answer (score 1):

'Neither, sorry' would fit perfectly as a response to being asked that question.

It is quick, short and to the point, and it isn't offensive or rude.